# M1 to M2 migration with percentage wise users

Tags: migration

We are doing migration of m1 which has big data. Db size around 80GB. Along with this complex customization done as per requirement. After many round of testing, we have doubt there may come critical errors when real users will start using the app when go live due to complex flow of order, shipment, promotions etc. It can not be ensure all the scenarios in test environment. For that we are planning to open m2 instance to some percentage of users and remaining users will be used m1 instance.

*Here only mobile application will be accessible by logged in user. There is no guest users journey and no web application.*

1. **Is this possible to go live with some percentage wise users?**
2. **What can be the impact for m1 user data when the user switch to m2 later?**
3. **Is there any reverse plan for m1 to m2 migration?**